# Write a regular expression that will match if the hexadecimal string 0x90 occurs more than three times in a row (i.e., 0x90 0x90 0x90)

Tags: regex, bash

I'm working on the above stated regex problem which is pretty simple: `(0x90\s*){4,}`
My questions is, how can I extend this to any hexadecimal number that appears more than 4 times.

Suppose I have the following in a file: 
0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90 
0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 
0x10 0x10 0x10

I want to write a regex that will match the first 2 lines since 0x90 appears more than 3 times and then 0x80 appears more than 3 times in it's own line. 0x10 appears exactly 3 times so there wouldn't be any match.

Here is what I've attempted:
`(0(x|x)[0-9a-fA-F]+\s*)\1{3,}`

The way it's written seems to work but only if there is atleast one space at the end of the line. For example, This regex will match the first line 0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90 only if there is a space after the last 0x90. I thought the issue is taken care of with the `\s*`?

Comment: Looks like you are confusing perl regular expressions (which support `\s`) with egrep extended regular expressions (which don't, but support `[:space:]` and `[:blank:]`). Which tool do you use to perform the matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it only matches if there is a space at the end in the example data, is because the backreference `\1` refers to group 1 that also has matched a space.

```
(0(x|x)[0-9a-fA-F]+\s*)\1{3,}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        group 1
```

Note that this capture group `(x|x)` matches either x or x which is the same as `(x)`

You can make a single capture group out of `(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)` followed by a whitespace char and a backreference to group 1 that is without a space 3 or more times.

```
(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)([[:space:]]\1){3,}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bhMy8y/1)

```
arr=(
"0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90"
"0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80"
"0x10 0x10 0x10"
"0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90   "
)
pattern='(0x[0-9a-fA-F]+)([[:space:]]\1){3,}'

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [[ "$i" =~ $pattern ]]
  then
    echo "Match: ${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"  
  else
    echo "No match: $i"
  fi     
done
```

Output

```
Match: 0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90
Match: 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80 0x80
No match: 0x10 0x10 0x10,
Match: 0x90 0x90 0x90 0x90
```

Comment: Nice solution ! seems to require bash >= 5.0. didn't work on `4.4.12(3)-release`

Comment: @Philippe I have tested this on Ubuntu with `4.4.12(1)-release` and `5.0.17(1)-release` and on a mac with `3.2.57(1)-release` I can not tell why it does not work for you unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, it's weird. I save your script in test.sh on Monterey@MacOS. Both `bash5.1.12 test.sh` and `bash3.2.57 test.sh` gave only `No match`. It seems depending on the underlying regex engine on the system.

Comment: This will match also `0x90 0x90 0x90 0x901`. It is not clear though from the OP's requirements whether or not it should match.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin We can solve that with (word) boundaries if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Extended Regex with grep:

`grep -E '(0x([[:xdigit:]]){2}[[:space:]]?){4,}'`

And since this question is tagged `bash`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read -r line || [ "$line" ]; do
  [[ $line =~ (0x([[:xdigit:]]){2}[[:space:]]?){4,} ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < inputfile
```

Comment: Unfortunately without backreferences this will match any adjacent hex numbers whether or not they are equal.